# Laravel 9 how to best query JSON object in JSON column?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-9

I've got a basic app up and running in the latest version of Laravel 9 that's utilising JSON columns for storing certain bits of data. I have a `job_type_rates` column on my `Client` model/table, where some have a value similar to:

```
[
  {
    "job_type": "8",
    "pay_rate": "15.45",
    "charge_rate": "18.45",
    "awr_pay_rate": "21.33",
    "awr_charge_rate": "26.77"
  }
]
```

What I would like to do is select all `clients` that have a `job_type` of `8`. I've tried to do `Client::whereJsonContains('job_type_rates->job_type', "8")->get()` but no results are returned, however that code would work if I didn't have an object in the column.

One way I can get around this is to create a pivot table and go down that route, but I was wondering if anyone had come up against this before and perhaps used a closure or similar?

Comment: You have an object in an array, but you are not referencing the array

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's what I can't seem to do through the query though, the Laravel docs don't seem to cover this?

Comment: To be fair, it looks like this data should have been stored in a more traditional way in a table, and accessing it would have been simple

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know, and I can go down that road as I've said in the question, but I'm wondering if this is possible first

Comment: Turns out `Client::whereJsonContains('job_type_rates', ["job_type" => "8"])->get()` is possible and works, but I think I'll refactor this regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @RiggsFolly I tried this code:

`Client::whereJsonContains('job_type_rates', ["job_type" => "8"])->get()`

And it works, it returns the expected results. As far as I'm aware this isn't in the Laravel docs (which mostly show single value examples).

I think it's still better to extract this out into a pivot table or similar, but I hope this helps someone!